# Global sections of Punctured Variety/Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $x \in X$ be a (edit: closed) point in a scheme. If $X$ is sufficiently nice (e.g noetherian and integral or even a variety), can we write $H^0(X \backslash \{x\}, \mathcal{O}_{X \backslash \{x\}})$ as some kind of localization/ in terms of $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$? Apologies if this is obvious, I'm a bit rusty here.

In the affine case if $X = \text{Spec} \ R$, I can see $X \backslash \{x\} = D(f_1) \cup \dots \cup D(f_l)$ for some elements $f_i$.

Comment: Are you aware of Hartog's phenomenon ? I.e if $\dim X \geq 2$ then $H^0(X \backslash \{x\}, O_{X \backslash \{x\}}) = H^0(X, O_X)$

Comment: If $X$ is affine, i.e. $\operatorname{Spec}R$ for an integral noetherian domain $R$, then the global sections are $\bigcap_{\mathfrak p \neq x} R_{\mathfrak p}$. If $R$ is at least two-dimensional and $R$ is normal, then this equals $R$.

Comment: @N.H I am! In fact I was trying to apply it to another problem in a different form, and missed it here. Thanks!!

Comment: @N.H. You need normality for this.

Comment: ah normality. most of my objects are normal. let me think if this is enough

Comment: Also note that $x$ must be a closed point. If not you do not even know how $X \setminus \{x\}$ is a scheme to begin with.

Comment: yes sorry closed can be assumed

Comment: Ah so I can't use Hartog, but this has helped. Actually @MooS you have answered my question, if you put that in an answer I will tick it etc

Comment: @MooS : thanks for the correction !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proposition 3.29 in the book Algebraic Geometry by Görtz/Wedhorn states that for an integral scheme $X$ and an open subset $U$, we have:

$$\mathcal O_X(U) = \bigcap_{z \in U} \mathcal O_{X,z}$$
, where the intersection is taken in the function field of $X$.

In your particular case, this tells us

$$\mathcal O_X(X \setminus \{x\}) = \bigcap_{z \neq x} \mathcal O_{X,z}.$$

If $X$ is at least two-dimensional, this intersection will run through all local rings at co-dimension one points. In particular if $X$ is also normal, the intersection equals $\mathcal O_X(X)$ by Hartog's lemma.